# Writing Hive dynamic partition using HCatalog issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I'm facing a problem when inserting data into Hive table using dynamic partitions.

I have an existing table with one ordinary column and one partition column and I'm trying to insert data into these columns. My code:

```
// Preparing writer
WriteEntity.Builder builder = new WriteEntity.Builder();
WriteEntity entity = builder.withDatabase(DATABASE_NAME).withTable(TABLE_NAME).withPartition(null).build();
HCatWriter masterHCatWriter = DataTransferFactory.getHCatWriter(entity, CUSTOM_CONFIG);
WriterContext writerContext = masterHCatWriter.prepareWrite();
HCatWriter hCatWriter = DataTransferFactory.getHCatWriter(writerContext);

// Preparing record to be written
List<HCatRecord> hCatRecordsBatch = new ArrayList<HCatRecord>();
HCatRecord hCatRecord = new DefaultHCatRecord(2);
hCatRecord.set(0, "aaa");
hCatRecord.set(1, "bbb");
hCatRecordsBatch.add(hCatRecord);

// Writing record
hCatWriter.write(hCatRecordsBatch.iterator());
```

But I'm getting exception:

```
org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 9001 : Exception occurred while processing HCat request : Failed while writing. Cause : org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2010 : Invalid partition values specified : Unable to configure dynamic partitioning for storage handler, mismatch between number of partition values obtained[0] and number of partition values required[1]
at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.transfer.impl.HCatOutputFormatWriter.write(HCatOutputFormatWriter.java:112)
at ...private classes...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2010 : Invalid partition values specified : Unable to configure dynamic partitioning for storage handler, mismatch between number of partition values obtained[0] and number of partition values required[1]
at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatBaseOutputFormat.configureOutputStorageHandler(HCatBaseOutputFormat.java:156)
at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileRecordWriterContainer.configureDynamicStorageHandler(FileRecordWriterContainer.java:264)
at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileRecordWriterContainer.write(FileRecordWriterContainer.java:183)
at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileRecordWriterContainer.write(FileRecordWriterContainer.java:53)
at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.transfer.impl.HCatOutputFormatWriter.write(HCatOutputFormatWriter.java:98)
... 8 more
```

I went through the code of hive library and it looks like the method `prepareWrite()` called on master node is getting wrong schema. It loads schema with just ordinary columns (partition columns are missing) and after that, value from the inserting record for the partition column can't be retrieved (it is in fact said in the exception `...number of partition values obtained[0]`...). There is same problem [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286256/adding-partitions-to-hive-from-a-mapreduce-job/23208089#23208089) but in my case I can't append column to schema because it is packed in `prepareWrite()` method.

I'm using libraries by Cloudera version 5.3.2 (it means Hive version 0.13.1)

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: In the HCat documentation, all examples for "dynamic partitioning" refer to MapReduce, natively or thru Pig. On the other hand HCatWriter belongs to a *"data transfer API for parallel input and output without using MapReduce"*. My guess is that dynamic partitioning is not supported, period.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The documentation of this is really poor. But If you check the link from my post to the StackOverflow question, there is almost the same problem in MapReduce (partitions are not loaded into schema). But in MapReduce I can append partition columns on my own. In data transfer API it is not possible :( (it is managed by prepareWrite() method)

Comment: The post you mention was about an EXTERNAL table; and the HCat wiki states that dynamic partitioning was indeed *"broken"* for EXTERNAL tables from V0.5 to V0.11 included  -- so it's not really the same issue.

Comment: If I understand well, "broken" dynamic partitioning refer to a different problem then me and "david1977" (in the mentioned post) are talking about. Anyway I'm using version 0.13.1 and we should focus on my issue.